# bar plot out of sequence

Tags: r, ggplot2

The x axis on the below chart runs from 10 to 20 to 5. I can't figure out why it does not run in sequence. Any help is appreciated

```
    library(ggplot2)
    source <- c("Asia", "Africa", "European", "America")
    wild <- c(10,5,20,5)
    domestic <- c(12,3,10,10)
    genome <- c(20,1,15,30)
    dataset <- as.data.frame(cbind(source, wild, domestic, genome)
    
    ggplot(dataset, aes(x = source, y = wild)) +
             geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
                coord_flip()
```

[image: here is the output]

Comment: It's because `cbind` converts the data to an all-character matrix, so your `wild` data has become a character instead of numeric. You can fix this by using `aes(x = source, y = as.numeric(wild))`. Alternatively, you can do this: `dataset <- cbind.data.frame(source, wild, domestic, genome)`.

Comment: Skip `cbind` entirely, the standard pattern for putting vectors in a data frame is `dataset <- data.frame(source, wild, domestic, genome)`. You only need `cbind` if some of the objects are already data frames or matrices.

Comment: Gregor-That did it. Thanks!

Comment: Teunbrand-that worked as well.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1.Don't use `cbind` for mixed variables (from `?cbind`: "The type of a matrix result determined from the highest type of any of the inputs in the hierarchy raw < logical < integer < double < complex < character < list .") -> i.e. if one of the arguments to `cbind` is character variable the resulting matrix will be of type "character"

2.There is no need for `cbind` within a `as.data.frame` call

3.There is no need for `as.data.frame` when `data.frame` will do ;)

```
library(ggplot2)

source <- c("Asia", "Africa", "European", "America")
wild <- c(10,5,20,5)
domestic <- c(12,3,10,10)
genome <- c(20,1,15,30)
dataset <- data.frame(source, wild, domestic, genome)
                         
ggplot(dataset, aes(x = source, y = wild)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]